# Using a list in a function python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
file = open('Info.txt', 'r')
x = str(file.read())
file.close()
info = re.findall(r'\w+', x)
j = len(info)
Fname = [0] * j

def FirstName(info, j, FName):
    i = 0

    n = 0
    while i<j:
        name = info[i]
        name = name.upper()
        name = list(name)
        Fname[n] = name[0]
        i = i + 3
        n = n + 1
```

I am trying to use the list "FName" in the function I defined as "Firstname". But when i run the program, I get an error stating that "Fname is not defined".

The solution is probably very simple but I am new to python.

Thanks

Comment: Capitalization matters.

Comment: `def FirstName(info, j, FName):` --> `def FirstName(info, j, Fname):`

Comment: I have no idea what that function was supposed to do, but it does not raise "Fname is not defined". `Fname` is defined. `FName` is defined too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's play, spot the difference:

- `FName`
- `Fname`

Perhaps you forgot the casing you were using. Or perhaps your font/screen makes it hard to distinguish `Fn` and `FN`.

Both of these are bad excuses, because PEP8 tells us you shouln't have been trying to type either of these in the first place. Stick to using `snake_case` everywhere for function and variable names, and you won't make this mistake again:

```
file = open('Info.txt', 'r')
x = str(file.read())
file.close()
info = re.findall(r'\w+', x)
j = len(info)
f_name = [0] * j

def first_name(info, j, f_name):
    i = 0

    n = 0
    while i<j:
        name = info[i]
        name = name.upper()
        name = list(name)
        f_name[n] = name[0]
        i = i + 3
        n = n + 1
```